# Counting the number of pattern occurrences in a certain column with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search the column Name of a certain table to see how many rows have a Name value that matches a certain pattern. For example, if the pattern I am looking for is `%Peter%` and in this table there are 5 rows with the Name values:

```
Peter
Peter Smith
George Peter
Peter Peter
Carl
```

I want to obtain the value `4`. I tried to use `COUNT`, but don't know how to combine it for example with LIKE. How do I go about to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why didn't `LIKE` work for you, but this SHOULD do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table
WHERE name LIKE '%Peter%'
```

Comment: Most likely he didn't use the percentage signs

Comment: I tried this, but get a syntax error near the pattern. This was the exact code I used: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM patient WHERE Name LIKE '%Peter%'

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. That code is flawless :) See it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80a389/2). If you could reproduce the error in the fiddle I've just linked then I could help you with that, but without any information there isn't much I can do

Comment: Nevermind. Turns out the error was coming from another line of code, rookie mistake :) Thanks!

Comment: Great. As long as the issue is solved everything is fine then :) Btw, no need to say thanks, that's what accepting answers is there for :D